# Placing variable in URL with Java for Android

Tags: java, android, swift

Using Android Studio, and Java: How can I take a text field entered variable and push it into a URL that will ultimately render information into a table view.

With swift for iOS I would use something like:

```
        self.getRedditJSON("http://placeprint.xyz/index.php?show=\(usernamesf)&long=\(billtype)")
```

In this swift case usernamesf and billtype are variables that were entered through a text field.

To render the table with Swift I would use:

```
var tableData = []


//here it
func getRedditJSON(whichReddit : String){


    let mySession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: whichReddit)!
    let networkTask = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler : {data, response, error -> Void in
        var err: NSError?
        var theJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSMutableDictionary
        let results : NSArray = theJSON["birthdate"] as NSArray



        self.tableData = results
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {      self.redditListTableView.reloadData() })
    })

       networkTask.resume()
   }
```

Need to convert this to Java, please, so it can be run on android device.

Comment: `String username = yourEditText.getText().toString(); String URL = "bla.bla.com/pro.php?username="+username;`

Comment: If you mean using a template string to put variable parts, you ca use MessageFormat class to format your String e.g. MessageFormat.format("http://placeprint.xyz/index.php?show={0}&long={1}", usernamef_variable, billtype_variable").

Comment: Randyka, that is Java?

Comment: Thank you Babak. I believe that will help.